# Do I need a UK transit visa when flying from Pakistan to Canada with Air Canada codeshared with Etihad Airways?

Tags: uk, air-travel, canada, lhr, pakistan

I'm flying from Pakistan to Canada, I do have a stopover in UK of 4 hours. My flights lands on terminal 3 and my next flight is from terminal 2. I have booked directly with Air Canada and flight has been codeshared with Etihad Airways until arrival at London Heathrow. From London Heathrow, it is with Air Canada.

I want to know, in my situation do I need a transit visa to move from terminal 3 to 2, or just for any other case, in my situation do I still need it?

Looking forward to early responses.

Comment: Have you tried to use https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa? What documents do you hold to enter Canada?

Comment: Without your nationality we can not answer this question as some people need transfer visa even when staying airside. But the links in the comment and the duplicate question give you the tools to find out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

LHR has internal transfer path where you can transfer between terminals without crossing the UK border. I've transferred from T3 to T2 before without any passport control in between. [Follow the purple "Connections" signs](https://www.heathrow.com/connecting-flights), they should take you to a bus that goes between the terminals.

Comment: This is helpfull but might not be enough if OP needs a visa even when staying airside.

Comment: @Willeke I wasn't aware that such a thing even exists, but apparently it does. Not sure though how it is enforced since there's no border control anywhere. In any case, the OP clearly has a right to enter to Canada, which is enough even if he needed a direct airside transit visa (https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/pakistan/transit/somewhere_else/no). Basically, according to their website, if you have the visa to your destination - you're good to go.

Comment: It is enforced by airlines not letting you board the plane if you need such a visa.